# Is there a tutorial, code project, or example of using MEF to extend the Vs2010 solution explorer context menus?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, contextmenu, mef

I have an existing legacy style `IDTExtensibility2, IDTCommandTarget` Extension that I would like to remake using MEF for vs2010, but I can't find any resources concerning VS2010 MEF and context menu changes. If it happened to be deployable via .vsix all the better.

Are there resources out there specific to MEF based context menu extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2010 there is no way to use MEF to extend these scenarios.  Changing context menus in Visual Studio 2010 requires the same approach as 2008 and prior.

Comment: Thanks, I wound up making the regular add in use `MEF` to locate it's UI. - more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495902/can-you-hydrate-a-static-property-using-mef